# Graphing multivariate functions by hand? Impossible?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

My question here is derivative of my last one but for increased brevity of both questions I've separated them. I'm exploring the following function for learning:$$f(x,\ y) = (x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2$$

And a graphic (courtesy of GeoGebra):
[image]

Now, for my question. How would I graph $f(x,\ y) = x^2 + y^2$ by hand? Would I have to assume $x$ and $y$ both as inputs, and then evaluate them for $z$? I surely can't approach it the way I do with a function of $x$ only, where I can evaluate everything at different $x$.

I'm leaning towards it being extremely hard or near impossible to graph them hence why we use computers, but knowing *exactly* why is what I'm most keen to understand. Since there are two inputs, any arbitrary pair of alike or unalike inputs of $x$ and $y$ respectively have an output $z$, i.e. there is a $z$ for $x = 2$ with $y = 0.22222$ just as there is a $z$ for $x = 1$ with $y = 1$, and thus too many points to plot. Is this the correct thinking? If not, why, and what is the correct thinking?

Comment: What does the graph of $x^2 + y^2 = c$ look like for fixed values of $c$?  One way to approach $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is to think about stacking graphs of $x^2 + y^2 = c$ as $c$ changes.

Comment: What's difficult?  For a given height $z$ The cross-section is a circle of radius $\sqrt z$ centered at $(2,2,z)$. for your first function.  For the second, the center is $(0,0,z)$.

Comment: DMcMor and @lulu So it's like stacking circles, but the radius increases as $z$ increases. How would I know the rate at which the radius increases?

Comment: The radius is given!  at height $z$ you have $x^2+y^2=z$ so the radius is $\sqrt z$.

Comment: Oh, so in other words the radius is a function of $x$ and $y$ as well since $z^{1/2} = (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$?

Comment: It is not easy draw 3-D graphs on 2D paper.  Some information will be compressed.  Choose the features that you think are most relevant an make sure that they get expressed.  One technique you can apply.  Fix $x,y$ or $z$ and draw the contours for the free variables, and then choose a new fix and draw a new contour.

Comment: If you function is symmtric or close to. You can think of one variable at a time, then add the other one. For example, $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ you probably know how $f(x) = x^2$ looks like. Okey, image the grapf of $f(x) = x^2$ in your head. Then let it rotate around the $f(x)$ axis. Now you have the graph of $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ in your head. With the same thinking you can detemine the looks of $f(x,y) = |x| + |y|$ for example, which were another "must need to know how it looks" function from my calculus.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few useful tricks when it comes to drawing the graph of a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables by hand:

1. Analyze the level sets $f(x,y) = c$ of your function. This is typically a curve or a collection of curves so it is easier to draw. Hopefully, this implicit equation will be familiar to you (or you can try and isolate one of the variables) and since the function is constant on each such level set, you can try and draw a few level sets and then a few values of $f(x,y)$ above each level set.
2. Analyze the intersection of the graph $f(x,y)$ with planes that pass through the origin (or other point) and are orthogonal to the $xy$-plane. For example, the intersection of the graph of $f(x,y)$ with the $xz$ plane is given by $f(0,y)$ which is a one-variable function.

To see how those tricks are useful, consider for example the functions $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $g(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Both functions are non-negative, zero at the origin and the level sets on which they are constant are circles. The intersection of the graph of $f(x,y)$ with the $xz$ plane (or any other plane, as the function $f$ has rotation symmetry) is given by $f(0,y) = y^2$ so it looks like a parabola. Hence, the graph of $f$ will look like a paraboloid (obtained by rotating a parabola around an axis). The intersection of the graph of $g$ with the $xz$ plane is given by $g(0,y) = \sqrt{y^2} = |y|$ which looks like a two lines intersecting at the origin at 90 degrees. Hence, the graph of $g$ will be a cone (again, obtained by rotating the slice).

To practice, you can try and draw $x^2 - y^2, x^2, x^3 + x^2$ and so on using the tricks above.

Answer (score 1):

How do we graph normally? In the beginning we pick an x, get out a y. Then as you get better at graphing certain graphs become very familiar and you don't have to pick a ton of x values. For example $x^2+y^2=1$ you can recognize that graph is a circle with practice and without picking points. For 3D it's a similar process. Start by holding a variable constant. When $x=0$ we have $z=y^2$ which is a parabola. This translates to "along the plane $x=0$ we have a parabola". Repeating this process for both x and y we realize that we have all these parabolas and we can recognize our graph as a paraboloid.

Comment: I see. And when $x = 1$ we have$ z = 1 + y^2$ which is the same as when x = 0 but shifted up 1 in $z$ and so on and so forth. But would this not just be a bunch of parabolas all in the same plane?

Comment: $z=1+y^2$ is not a shift upward of when $x=0$ remember $x=$ a number is a plane in 3 dimensions. We're looking at cross sections here in order to piece together the entire thing

Comment: Forgive me, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. So we're piecing together several parabolas to form a paraboloid. How would $z = 1 + y^2$ then differ from $z = y^2$? And are there infinitely many parabolas on the plane x = 0?

Comment: Oh yes it is a shift upward but remember to get that shift we also changed the x value. And no there are not infinitely many planes on $x=0$ that was my bad

Answer (score 1):

Graphing a 3D graph by hand is not entirely feasible; you can, however, draw what is known as a **contour-plot**.

I.e for $z=(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2$, first plot the graph for $y=n$, where n is any desired number, lets say $2$. This would be the parabola $(x-2)^2$ on the $x$ vs $z$ graph. Then do the same, but for $y=1$, $y=3$, etc, on the same axes, depending on how much you want to show.

If my explanation lacks depth, you can find plenty on the subject just by googling "contour plot"

Comment: The *contours* here are also called level curves (because they correspond to curves where a function takes a constant value).